# Enter only arabic alphabets in textfield using regular expression

Tags: jquery, validation

I have some input text fields where users must enter only alphabets in some fields (or) only numbers in certain fields etc. i have implemented this in English using regular expressions but how to do it in arabic language.

Here is my Validation code for English

//enter only alphabets

```
 $(".alphaOnly").bind("keyup blur", function(e){


            if(e.keyCode!=37 && e.keyCode!=39 && e.keyCode!=32 && e.keyCode!=17 && e.keyCode!=8 && e.keyCode!=46 && !e.ctrlKey){
            $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z_ ]*$/,'') );


            }
        });
    $(".alphaOnly").bind("keydown blur", function(e){

            if($(this).val().length == 0){
                if(e.keyCode==32){
                    $(this).val("");
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }else{
            if(e.keyCode!=37 && e.keyCode!=39 && e.keyCode!=32 && e.keyCode!=17 && e.keyCode!=8 && e.keyCode!=46 && !e.ctrlKey){
            $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z_ ]*$/,'') );

            }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Arabic character set of list

```
[\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]
```

You can test using regex as follows:

```
function HasArabicCharacters(text)
{
    var arregex = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
    alert(arregex.test(text));
}
```

Arabic script in Unicode:

The Arabic script is contained in the following blocks:

```
Arabic (0600—06FF, 225 characters)
Arabic Supplement (0750—077F, 48 characters)
Arabic Extended-A (08A0—08FF, 39 characters)
Arabic Presentation Forms-A (FB50—FDFF, 608 characters)
Arabic Presentation Forms-B (FE70—FEFF, 140 characters)
Rumi Numeral Symbols (10E60—10E7F, 31 characters)
Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols (1EE00—1EEFF, 143 characters)
```

Unicodes are taken from wikipedia - [Arabic script in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_Unicode_block)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to only allow arabic and english alphabets.

I know it's not the best way to do it like that, but here is my code and it worked perfect:

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

         let set = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ أبجدهوزحطيكلمنسعفصقرشتثخذضظغ")


         if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: set.inverted) != nil {
            return false
        }
        return true  
    }
```

P.S. : Don't forget to set you textfield's delegate